# Eclipse stepping into methods

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am lost for words and ideas.  I am working with a polymorphic binary search tree where I need to compute the height of the tree.  The NonEmptyTree implements the Tree interface and has all of the necessary methods.  The problem I'm having is actually calling the height method.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and it's probably because I'm took close to the project that I can't seem to find probably the obvious issue.

There is also a class called EmptyTree which also implements the Tree interface.  Below are all of the relevant methods.

```
public class PolymorphicBST<K extends Comparable<K>, V>  {
    public int height() {
        return this.height();
}

public int height() {
    int lDepth = left.height();
    int rDepth = right.height();

    if (lDepth == 0 || rDepth == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (Math.abs(lDepth - rDepth) > 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    return Math.max(lDepth, rDepth) + 1;
}
```

The code in the heightAux method is used to calculate the actual height of the tree.  When I debug the program it never leaves the JUnit class no matter how many breakpoint I insert and how many times I press "step into".  When I press resume project I just get a StackOverflow error.  This is a school project so I'm not displaying all of the code just that which is relevant to the problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

So, I have know gotten rid of the auxiliary method since I don't think it's necessary to get the height.

Comment: There's not enough information, post the rest of your code, for example, where and how `heightAux()` is defined ?

Comment: Method `int height()` is implemented with an infinite recursion...

Comment: Shouldn't the "return this.height" call the appropriate class method based on whether the tree is empty or nonEmpty?  Thus, it will terminate based on the height method for each of those classes?

Comment: I just figured out the problem.  I needed to have it say root.height.  The root of the tree determined whether it was an EmptyTree or NonEmptyTree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public int height() {
       return this.height();
```

Your height() method is calling itself by saying this.height(). This will go into infinite loop since there is no exit point.

Comment: To call `height` method located outside of nested class: `NameOfTheParentClass.this.height()`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem. I needed to have it say root.height. The root of the tree determined whether it was an EmptyTree or NonEmptyTree